# two carousel in same page, materializecss

Tags: css, materialize

This is a materializecss carousel.
The first carousel works perfectly fine. If i want to create the second carousel on the same page it creates issue.

I have tried changing the class carousel to carousel1 and called
$('.carousel1.carousel-slider').carousel({full_width: true});

The second carousel is misaligned and carousel does not get initialised.

Need guidance.

```
<div class="carousel carousel-slider center" data-indicators="true">
    <div class="carousel-fixed-item center">
      <a class="btn waves-effect white grey-text darken-text-2">button</a>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item red white-text" href="#one!">
      <h2>First Panel</h2>
      <p class="white-text">This is your first panel</p>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item amber white-text" href="#two!">
      <h2>Second Panel</h2>
      <p class="white-text">This is your second panel</p>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item green white-text" href="#three!">
      <h2>Third Panel</h2>
      <p class="white-text">This is your third panel</p>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item blue white-text" href="#four!">
      <h2>Fourth Panel</h2>
      <p class="white-text">This is your fourth panel</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you please define "*not working*" and "*the output is wrong*"? Just a reminder that we can't see your screen, nor know what your *intended* output should be (unless you explicitly tell us)...

Comment: Have you tried giving each one an id and initialize it with the id's instead of with classes.

Comment: @SteveK your solution works fine. It will be good if you can put this as answer so that i can accept it. Will be useful for someone looking for the same. This is what fixed the issue $('#carousel2').carousel({full_width: true});

Comment: @ObsidianAge point noted and edited the question to be bit more descriptive. please note Steve K solution fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of initializing your carousel with classes give each carousel an id and then initiate them with the id's instead of the classes so each one is unique.